BTRFS won't remove missing disk?
I had a hard drive fail in my BTRFS raid10 array, and it is failing to remove. What am I missing? I already added a replacement drive /dev/sdf, but it won't let me remove the old failed drive.
dulanic@proxmox:~$ sudo btrfs device delete missing /mnt/tank
ERROR: error removing device 'missing': no missing devices found to remove
dulanic@proxmox:~$ sudo btrfs device delete /dev/sdg /mnt/tank
ERROR: not a block device: /dev/sdg
dulanic@proxmox:~$ sudo btrfs fi show /mnt/tank
Label: 'tank'  uuid: f43146ce-e69b-47b6-af7c-34c6be87de87
        Total devices 12 FS bytes used 57.51TiB
        devid    1 size 16.37TiB used 11.88TiB path /dev/sdd
        devid    2 size 16.37TiB used 11.86TiB path /dev/sdh
        devid    4 size 7.28TiB used 5.21TiB path /dev/sdk
        devid    5 size 16.37TiB used 11.96TiB path /dev/sdi
        devid    6 size 16.37TiB used 11.96TiB path /dev/sdn
        devid    7 size 16.37TiB used 11.96TiB path /dev/sdm
        devid    8 size 16.37TiB used 11.96TiB path /dev/sdo
        devid    9 size 16.37TiB used 11.96TiB path /dev/sdp
        devid   10 size 0 used 0 path /dev/sdg MISSING
        devid   11 size 7.28TiB used 7.28TiB path /dev/sdb
        devid   12 size 7.28TiB used 7.28TiB path /dev/sdc
        devid   13 size 14.55TiB used 634.00GiB path /dev/sdf


I have no experience with this whatsoever, but man 8 btrfs-device says: "If the filesystem is mounted in degraded mode (-o degraded), special term missing can be used […]". Is the filesystem mounted in degraded mode?

Have you tried using the devid number, i.e. sudo btrfs device remove 10 /mnt/tank?
